# Unable to update domain details using Godaddy API in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, godaddy-api

I'm trying to update nameserver for a domain that is currently registered using OTE Environment. I am able to register the domain but unable to update the nameserver for the registered domain. The error i receive is

**"INVALID_BODY\",\"fields\":[{\"code\":\"UNEXPECTED_TYPE\",\"message\":\"is not a array\",\"path\":\"records\"}"**

Below is my code.

**GoDaddyDomain.cs**

```
DomainUpdate sub = new DomainUpdate();


                sub.locked = true;
                sub.nameServers = new List<string>();
                sub.nameServers.Add("ns1.tsohost.co.uk");
                sub.nameServers.Add("ns2.tsohost.co.uk");
                sub.renewAuto = true;
                sub.subaccountId = "196209292";


                string _secret = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx";
                string _apikey = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx";

                string MessageType = "application/json";

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("sso-key", _apikey + ":" + _secret);

                    using (var requests = new HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Put, String.Format("https://api.ote-godaddy.com/v1/domains/MyTestDomain000001.com/records/")))
                    {
                        requests.Headers.Add("Accept", MessageType);


                        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                        var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sub);
                        requests.Content = new StringContent(value);
                        requests.Content.Headers.ContentType = System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(MessageType);

                        using (var responses = await client.SendAsync(requests).ConfigureAwait(false))
                        {
                            string responseXmls = await responses.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                            var codes = response.StatusCode;
                        }
                        requests.Content.Dispose();
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
```

**DomainUpdate.cs**

```
public class DomainUpdate
    {
        public bool locked { get; set; }
        public List<string> nameServers { get; set; }
        public bool renewAuto { get; set; }
        public string subaccountId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you check the serialized json object and use it in Postman? Basically I always re-check my calls to the api by putting them into a Postman collection.

Comment: Ah late comment! But yeah I don't exactly remember what was the issue, but I was that the name server that was not pointed for the domain. But like you said, option for postman browser was a right to identify the response.